# Assigning global variables within a local function in C#

Tags: c#

I have a program where I am assigning several variables from within a function. When I do the assignments manually it seems to work, but if I write a helper function the assignments only seem to hold within the helper function.

```
foo a, b
public void Setup(int v1, int v2, int v3)
{
    a = new foo(v1, v2);
    a.value = v3;
    b = new foo(v1, v2);
    b.value = v3;
}
```

the above code does what I want but when I try to simplify it by creating a local method to do the assignments, it doesnt seem to work

```
foo var a,b
public void Setup(int v1, int v2, int v3)
{
    void DoThings(foo temp, int _v1, int _v2, int _v3)
    {
        temp = new foo(_v1, _v2);
        temp.value = _v3;
    }
    DoThings(a, v1, v2, v3);
    DoThings(b, v1, v2, v3);
}
```

The above compiles properly but when I try to use a or b later in my code (in another function) I get that both are null even though I know the DoThings function ran. Is there a way to do what I am trying to accomplish or should I just do all the assignments as in the first example?

Comment: IMHO returning a foo is a better solution `foo DoThings(...){...} a = DoThings(...); ...`

Comment: "The above compiles properly" - No, it doesn't.

Comment: There are no global variables in your code. In fact, C# does not have global variables.

Answer (score 3):

This is a case of not understanding how parameters are passed.

Ignoring the design entirely, doing this `temp = new Foo(...)` just changes where *temp* is pointing to in memory.  That's all.

It used to be the address of the passed in parameter, but now it isn't.  So temp is pointing to a new address in memory that's pretty useless, because the original one is unchanged still pointing to the original address.

You can fix this by [passing by reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).

Simple code change shown below.  But I'd emphasize a deeper understanding of how C# passes parameters would help understand why this changes behavior.

```
void DoThings(ref foo temp, int _v1, int _v2, int _v3)
{
    temp = new foo(_v1, _v2);
    temp.value = _v3;
}
```

You must also pass by reference when calling:

```
DoThings(ref a, v1, v2, v3);
DoThings(ref b, v1, v2, v3);
```

This then behaves how you'd expect, and the difference is important and covered in depth in the linked documentation.